# Odd artifacts when using Unicode escapes in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have a bit of code that goes like this:

```
if temp < 244:
    return ("<-20 "+u"\u00B0"+"F")
```

However, when I run it, I get this:

```
"<-20 \xb0F"
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you *printing* the result of this function, or are you evaluating it in an interactive interpreter? There's a big difference.

Comment: I was printing it with pprint, which apparently uses repr().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the representation of the string, rather than at the string itself.

Maybe this will clarify:

```
>>> s = "<-20 "+u"\u00B0"
>>> s
u'<-20 \xb0'
>>> type(s)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> repr(s)
"u'<-20 \\xb0'"
>>> print s
<-20 °
>>> s == u"<-20 °"
True
>>> s == u'<-20 \xb0'
True
>>> s.encode('utf-8')
'<-20 \xc2\xb0'
s.encode('latin1')
'<-20 \xb0'
```

Comment: Just realized that myself. Whoops!